# How to Reset Validation after form submit in Angular 2

Tags: validation, angular2-forms

I've test form with some simple validation. My validation is working perfectly on time of submit form.

**HTML**

```
<section>
    <form (ngSubmit)="savePerson()" #personForm="ngForm">
      <div>
        <label for="name">Name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="person.name" required #name="ngModel" >
        <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="error">
          Name is required.
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="weight">Weight: </label>
        <input type="number" name="weight" [(ngModel)]="person.weight" min="20" #weight="ngModel">
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="weight.errors && (weight.dirty || weight.touched)" class="error">
        <p [hidden]="!weight.errors.min">
          Weight must be higher than a feather's. {{weight.value}} is way too low.
        </p>
        <p [hidden]="!weight.errors.max">
            Weight can't be higher than a Rancor's. {{weight.value}} is too high
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="height">Height: </label>
        <input type="number" name="height" [(ngModel)]="person.height">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label for="profession">Profession: </label>
        <select name="proffesion" [(ngModel)]="person.proffesion" #proffesion="ngModel" min=1>
          <option [ngValue]="0">Select Proffession</option>
          <option *ngFor="let p of allproffesion" [value]="p.id">{{p.title}}</option>
        </select>
        </div>
      <div>
        <p>{{message}}</p>
       <button type="submit" [disabled]="!personForm.form.valid">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
<button (click)="gotoPeoplesList()">Back to peoples list</button>
```

**TS**

```
export class AddPersonComponent { 
    person : Person = { id : 0, height : 0, weight : 0, name : "", proffesion : 0};
    message : String = "";
    allproffesion : Proffesion [];
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private peopleService:PeopleService){
        this.getAllProffession();
    }

    getAllProffession(){
        this.peopleService.getAllProffession().subscribe(i=>this.allproffesion = i);
    }
    gotoPeoplesList(){
      let link = ['/'];    
      this.router.navigate(link);
    }

    savePerson(){
        this.peopleService.addPerson(this.person).subscribe(i=>{ this.reset(i)});
    }

    reset(person1 : Person){
        if(person1.id != 0){
            console.log(this.person);
            this.message = "Person Added Successfully.!";
            this.person = { id : 0, height : 0, weight : 0, name : "", proffesion : 0};
        }
        else{
            this.message = "Something Went Wrong";
        }
    }
```

[image]
After Submitting Form:
[image]

> My issue is after submitting the form, **I want to reset validation. I don't want to reset form although**. As I want to show message for successful insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `FormGroup` [reset](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#!#reset-anchor) operation if you want to clear the `touched` and `dirty` flags of the form controls.  Internally this will mark all descendants as `pristine` and `untouched`.

The reset method also takes a map of the values for the form state so you can keep all (or some of the values from the previous form submission). See [this example](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset-usage-notes)

Also from your question:

> As I want to show message for successful insert

The form reset would not affect you displaying this as the `message` property is not part of the form - it's just a regular property on your component.

Comment: I have to change the structure of my code to make formgroup work. is Formgroup is better approach than the approach I have chosen?

Comment: I don't think you'd have to change your approach, you can keep using a template driven form and call `personForm.reset()`

Comment: Your second link (to the example) does not go to a page with the indicated example.

Answer (score 0):

In the savePerson method, you should invoke the FormGroup markAsPristine method.

This the official documentation of this method:
https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#markAsPristine

To get access to the FormGroup object in the component class, you can use @ViewChild.